# slicing pandas column using values from another column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, substring

So I have a dataframe with some text in one column.
I'm trying to find 2 strings within each row of the column, and then slice the row text between those two strings to get a substring. Something like this:

```
startinds = df[column].str.find("First Event = ")
endinds   = df[column].str.find("\nLast Event = ")

df["first_timestamp"] = df[column].str.slice(startinds,endinds)
```

Now this doesn't work because `startinds` and `endinds` are series, so I can't use them as indices for slicing the strings in `column`.

Anyone know a way I can access the values to do the substrings on each row?

Example Input:

```
    Data
0   "Blahblah
     First Event = 09/20/2017 12:00:00
     Last Event = 09/20/2017 13:00:00
     Blahblahblah"
1   "Blahblahblahblah
     Blahablahblah
     First Event = 09/20/2017 12:30:00
     Last Event = 09/20/2017 12:45:00
     Blahblahblah"
```

Output:

```
    first_timestamp
0   "First Event = 09/20/2017 12:00:00"
1   "First Event = 09/20/2017 12:30:00"
```

Comment: It's an [open issue on github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8748). You'll most likely have to do it manually.

Comment: Do `"First Event = " + df.Data.str.extract('(?<=First Event = )(.*)(?=\\\\nLast Event)', expand=False)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unlike the answer in the comments, this approach with `Series.str.extract` should work:

```
df['first_timestamp'] = df['Data'].str.extract('(First Event = .+)')

#                                                 Data  \
# 0  Blahblah\nFirst Event = 09/20/2017 12:00:00\nL...   
# 1  Blahblahblahblah\nFirst Event = 09/20/2017 12:...   
# 
#                      first_timestamp  
# 0  First Event = 09/20/2017 12:00:00  
# 1  First Event = 09/20/2017 12:30:00
```

The pattern `'(First Event = .+)'` captures a group (i.e. `()`) with "First Event = " followed by one or more characters (i.e. `.+`), stopping at a newline (the `.` character matches anything except a newline).

Comment: @andraiamatrix the `.` character in regular expressions matches anything except a line break (so `.+` matches one or more of anything except a line break). Based on your updated question, it looks like `df['Data'].str.extract('(First Event = .+)')` will capture your first_timestamp group. I'll update my answer.

Comment: So I noticed `.+` stops at a newline, but it doesn't stop at a carriage-return, `\r` (which it turns out is what is in my data). Is there something that will stop at either? I tried `(First Event = .+)[\r\n]` but that didn't stop the carriage-returns from appearing in my output.

Comment: Instead of using `.`, can you try this? `df['Data'].str.extract('(First Event = [^\n\r]+)')`

Answer (score 4):

To complete your slicing method you can use lambda i.e store the `startinds` and `endinds` in df and then slice the string based on columns using lambda across column i.e (note you need an escape character to get the `\n`)

```
df['startinds'] = df['Data'].str.find("First Event = ")
df['endinds']  = df['Data'].str.find("\\nLast Event = ")

df.apply(lambda x : str(x['Data'])[x['startinds']:x['endinds']],1 )
```

Output:

```
0    First Event = 09/20/2017 12:00:00
1    First Event = 09/20/2017 12:30:00
dtype: object
```

Comment: My bad. The \n is a newline character. I just threw them in the sample data instead of doing actual newlines. but it's not a literal backslash. I've edited the original

Comment: A small doubt is First Event always in the second line?

Comment: No. It can be anywhere. Sometimes it might not actually be in the data. I've realized i'll have to use the regex solution because this string slicing doesn't work when the keyword doesn't show up.